# WPF Using Resource Variables in xaml

Tags: wpf, resources

I have a Global string in my App.xaml I want to uses in a UserControl xaml how do I reference it?

```
<Application.Resources>
   <sys:String x:Key="Assembly">Zpg</sys:String>
</Application.Resources>
```

I also have a valiable in the UserControl Resources do I use this in a simila way in the xaml?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="Dictionary">Test</sys:String>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I hope that makes some sense, basically I have the following I want to replace with reference to the above variables as I will use them a lot.

```
Text="{LocText Key=MyString, Dict=Test, Assembly=Zpg}"
```

Thanks,

James

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680146/using-system-types-in-xaml-as-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Text="{LocText Key=MyString, Dict={StaticResource Dictionary}, Assembly={StaticResource Assembly}}"
```