# What is the datatype of this width?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I'm trying to define a local resource in my xaml which is supposed to be the width of my cells, so rather than going:

```
<Setter Property="ColumnStretchMinWidth" Value="75"/>
<Textbox Width="75" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="75" />
...etc
```

I can go

```
<Setter Property="ColumnStretchMinWidth" Value="{StaticResource MinCellWidth}"/>
<Textbox Width="{StaticResource MinCellWidth}" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="{StaticResource MinCellWidth}" />
```

But when I define this constant, I get binding errors saying it can't cast. When I go

```
<System:String x:Key="MinCellWidth">"75"</s:String>
```

I get an error saying it can't convert from String to Double for some controls. When I go

```
<System:Double x:Key="MinCellWidth">"75"</s:Double>
```

I get an error saying it can't convert from Double to string for other controls (like the ColumnDefinition, where "*" widths are allowed).

What is the magic type of the hardcoded `="75"` that lets it be converted to the appropriate type for each control. How can I define a resource that can be used in all these different places?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using system types in XAML as resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680146/using-system-types-in-xaml-as-resources)

Comment: @Sohnee - Doesn't matter now, because this question is answered, but the other question was looking for the type that worked for ColumnDefinitions. I was looking for a solution that allowed a constant to be used for all these types - not just ColumnDefinitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic type of ColumnDefinition.Width is [GridLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.width.aspx), and it needs a resource of that type. Just as TextBox.Width needs a double.

```
<s:Double x:Key="minCellWidth">55</s:Double>
<sw:GridLength x:Key="minGridWidth">55</sw:GridLength>
```

Comment: Strange - I thought that since I could enter it plainly in the xaml (without any sort of type definition) that there was some sort of variant type for xaml. Okay, so I'll need two constants - but if the textbox width is "Auto" how can I get fit that into a double constant? I know that when you set Width="Auto", the width is stored as NAN, but that doesn't happen automatically in the same way when "Auto" is assigned to the `cellWidth` StaticResource.

Comment: Can't You use `<sys:Double x:Key="minCellWidth">NaN</sys:Double>`?

Answer (score 0):

This does not have anything to do with the type of `"75"`, it's a string, the thing is that string literals get converted using [**type converters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126043.aspx).

This should work by the way as bindings apply type converters as well:

```xml
MinWidth="{Binding Source={StaticResource MinCellWidth}}"
```

Comment: Now where I set the width to "Auto" I'm getting the error "Cannot convert Auto to GridLength". Using Auto directly (rather than as a StaticResource) works though.

Comment: @Alain: I edited my answer as i made a wrong assumption about the problem. As your question is `What is the datatype of this width?` i assumed you had problems with the `ColumnDefinition.Width` which is the only exotic type here.

Comment: With `MinWidth="{Binding Source={StaticResource MinCellWidth}}"` how is `MinCellWidth` defined? I cannot find a way to define it that works for all three, yet the hard coded `"75"` works for all three.

Comment: @Alain: It's `<sys:String>75</sys:String>` (Drop the quotes, they belong to the XAML of attributes), double or int might work as well.

Comment: `<s:String x:Key="MinCellWidth">75</s:String>` gives me a runtime error: `Cannot convert the value in attribute 'MinWidth' to object of type 'System.Double'. '75' is not a valid value for property 'MinWidth'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.ColumnDefinition' in markup file`

Comment: @Alain: You are not applying a binding as i noted in my question, are you?

Comment: Yeah, I tried every type I could think of, I always get one of the controls saying it can't be converted. Also, I get the same error whether I go `MinWidth="{Binding Source={StaticResource MinCellWidth}}"` or just `MinWidth="{StaticResource MinCellWidth}"`

Comment: @Alain: That should not happen, it works for me with binding and every (reasonable) type.